# Run Callback after Gridview Sort

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm sorting a gridview inside an update panel. When the user clicks on the column header, the gridview resorts itself fine. However, after the sort, I' like to run a javascript function called MyScript.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an OnSorted event to the GridView:

```
void GridView_Sorted(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var myScript = ....
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "afterSort", myScript, true);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this client-side?

Answer (score 2):

You could subscribe for the [endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) event on the [`PageRequestManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx).

```
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    // the request finished => run your script here
}
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this client-side?

Comment: Sorry, I meant is there a way on the client to run a script that listens to the event "I just received an updated version of the gridview". I can always do something like $('#MyGrid').change() but that is a listener for a change in the gridview itself. I'm looking for a way to listen to an ajax replt event. The code you provided is for the code behind file; i'm looking for front-end javascript/jquery code. Thanks

Comment: @frenchie, the code I provided is pure javascript. No code behind. This code is part of the MS Ajax library used by the UpdatePanel. So you subscribe for the `endRequest` event which will be trigerred by the UpdatePanel once the AJAX request completes and the `EndRequestHandler` **javascript** function will be invoked.

Comment: It's javascript invoked from the server. I meant javascript code that you put in the browser's page and that listens to a postack and that's not invoked from the server